# Позиционирование тeкстa

Tags: html, css

Как сделать текст как под цифрой 1 средствами HTML/CSS/PHP?

У меня получается только 2 вариант

[image: Формат]

Comment: text-align: right для второй строчки

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Решение через flex

```css
div{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>abc - [AA] abc</span>
  <span>[BB] abc</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение через `table`

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc - </td>
    <td>[AA] abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>[BB] abc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```